# How to exclude one parent id from post_parent' => 'any', in WordPress / bbPress?

Tags: bbpress

The code below works well however I would like to exclude one parent id from he output.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to have `[ post_parent' => 'any']` to everything except parent id="5150".
Is this possible?

```
if ( bbp_has_topics( 
   array( 
     'author' => 0, 
     'show_stickies' => false, 
     'order' => 'DESC', 
     'post_parent' => 'any', 
     'posts_per_page' => 5
   ) 
) ) {

      bbp_get_template_part( 'bbpress/loop', 'topics' );
     }`
```

Thank you

Comment: Have yo tried using `post_parent__not_in`? seems like this function uses WP_Query so all options you can pass to WP_Query should be available in this function as well.

Comment: Hello Buttered Toast, thank you for your reply and it got me to look for more info and I found this page ( https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-posts-pages-and-post-types--cms-23164)  from that statement you provided so I went and ahead and tried it but perhaps my syntax is wrong?  I tried if ( bbp_has_topics( array( 'author' => 0, 'show_stickies' => false, 'order' => 'DESC','post_parent__not_in' => array('5150', '6833'), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ) ))
 bbp_get_template_part( 'bbpress/loop', 'topics' );  Anyc hance you may know what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from the post IDs in the array, so `array( 5150, 6833 ),`

Comment: Thank you Tony for replying. I gave it a go but it didn't work,. Is there anything else I should try? All I want to do is get all topics except from Forum 5150 .